# How to install manpages on FreeNAS 9.3?

Tags: installation, freebsd, freenas, man

I'm having enourmous trouble installing manpages on FreeNAS 9.3 (based on FreeBSD 9.2-RELEASE-p15). I tried:

- installing `pc-sysinstall` from ftp://ftp.freebsd.org/pub/FreeBSD/ports/amd64/packages-9.2-release/Latest/ with `pkg_add` because it comes closest to `sysinstall` which might perform the installation (why do I have to use a system installation script to install something that can be installed with a package manager or from source?) (mentioned in [this blog entry](http://www.cyberciti.biz/tips/howto-install-man-info-pages-and-other-package-set.html))
- installing `de-manpages-de` from above mentioned ports site does nothing
- `portsnap` is not available and not installable from above mentioned ports site
- `bsdinstall` which is described as successor of `sysinstall` [on freebsdnews.com](https://www.freebsdnews.com/2011/02/19/bsdinstall-freebsd-installer-sysinstall-pc-sysinstall/) is so unintuitive that I'm risking to partition my disk
- `csup` or `cvsup` (haven't figured out the difference yet) seems to be used for getting sources from CVS and I didn't find any descriptions applying to FreeBSD > 4 and assume naively that it is outdated (taking into account the decrease of usage of CVS in the last decade and that I found none of the files described in [the only usage instructions I found](http://www.freebsddiary.org/cvsup.php))
- There's no `/usr/ports/` directory!

Comment: This is highly specialized software, you almost do not need command line. Is there serious reason to add man pages?